# Reset game, delete canvas

Tags: python, oop, canvas, tkinter

I stuck with my overall game that I will create a reset button. I want to restore the game to its original state. I have tried to restore lists, etc., without any positive result.

Someone who can give me some good suggestion or a solution?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- codieren: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from pygame import mixer


#Skapar fönster och dess inställningar
win = Tk() #Skapar fönster
win.title("Play High or Low Card") #Fönsterrubrik
win.geometry("700x550") #Fönsterstorlek
win.config(bg="#188200")
mixer.init(44100)

turns = int()
score = int(1)

try: #Kontrollerar så att programmet hittar ljudfilerna
    deal = mixer.Sound("Python/projekt/sound/deal.wav")
    shuffle = mixer.Sound("Python/projekt/sound/shuffle.wav")
    winner = mixer.Sound("Python/projekt/sound/win.wav")
    loser = mixer.Sound("Python/projekt/sound/miss.wav")
except: #Felmeddelande skrivs ut om dessa inte hittas
    print ("Kunde inte öppna ljudfilerna")


class Card(object): #Skapar klass innehållande information och metoder för korten

    RANKS = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"] #Lista på kortens värde

    SUIT = ["Python/projekt/bilder/hearts.png", "Python/projekt/bilder/spades.png", "Python/projekt/bilder/diamond.png", "Python/projekt/bilder/clubs.png"] #Lista på kortens valörer samt sökväg till bilder på dessa

    def __init__(self, rank, suit): #initierar/gör känt
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.rank + self.suit
        return rep

    def draw(self): #Metod som ritar upp grafiken/korten

        bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.suit).resize((10, 10))) #Öppnar upp bild, bestämmer dess storlek. Tar emot sökväg från SUIT

        cardGraph = Canvas(cardHolder, width=70, height=100, bg="White", bd=1, relief='solid', highlightthickness=2) #Skapar och bestämmer utseende för canvas
        cardGraph.photo=bg #Sätter bilden som öppnas i bg, som bakgrund

        cardGraph.create_image(10,10, image=bg, anchor=CENTER) #left/up
        cardGraph.create_image(53,93, image=bg, anchor=CENTER) #right/down

        cardGraph.create_text(20, 10, text=self.rank, font=("Helvetica", 8, "bold")) #left/up
        cardGraph.create_text(63, 93, text=self.rank, font=("Helvetica", 8, "bold")) #right/down
        cardGraph.create_text(36, 50, text=self.rank, font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold")) #middle

        cardGraph.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=CENTER) #Bestämmer position för canvas

        return cardGraph

class Hand(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.draw_card_stack = [] #Array för ritade kort

    def __str__ (self):
        if self.cards:
            rep = ""
            for card in self.cards:
                rep += str(card) + " "
        else:
            rep = "<empty>"
        return rep

    def add(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)

class Deck(Hand):

    global CardValueHist
    CardValueHist = []

    def populate(self): #Bygger upp kortleken
        for suit in Card.SUIT:
            for rank in Card.RANKS:
                self.add(Card(rank, suit))

    def shuffle(self): #Blandar och målar upp kort, samt uppdaterar canvas
        import random
        random.shuffle(self.cards)
        DrawCard = self.cards[0]
        card_graph = DrawCard.draw()

        deal.play()

        self.draw_card_stack.append(card_graph)
        if len(self.draw_card_stack) > 3: #Kontrollerar längden på listan. Om listan är större än 3
            self.draw_card_stack[0].destroy() #Tar bort canvas
            del self.draw_card_stack[0] #Snyggar till listan


    def setValue(self): #Sätter värde på korten
        global CardValue
        CardValue = 0
        rank = self.cards[0].rank

        #Kollar upp vilken rank kortet har, sätter därefter värde
        if rank == 'K':
            CardValue += 13
            CardValueHist.append(CardValue)
        elif rank == 'Q':
            CardValue += 12
            CardValueHist.append(CardValue)
        elif rank == 'J':
            CardValue += 11
            CardValueHist.append(CardValue)
        elif rank == 'A':
            CardValue += 1
            CardValueHist.append(CardValue)
        else:
            CardValue += int(rank) #Sätter kortets egna rank som värde (2-10)
            CardValueHist.append(CardValue)

    def reset(self):
            global turns
            global score     

            score = 1
            turns = 0 #Återställer värdet i
            decket = Deck()
            decket.populate()

            turnEnt.delete(0, END) #Tar bort allt ifrån Entry-widgeten
            turnEnt.insert(0, int(turns)) #Fyller den på nytt, men nu med ett nytt värde
            scoreTot.delete(0, END) #Tar bort allt ifrån Entry-widgeten
            scoreTot.insert(0, int(score)) #Fyller den på nytt, men nu med ett nytt värde

            lower.config(state='active')
            higher.config(state='active')
            restart.config(state='disable')

class game(Deck):

    def helper(self): #Funktion för att öppna hjälptextfilen
        try:
            textFile = open("helper.txt", "r") #Öppnar och läser fil
            data = textFile.read() #Ger variabel data från filen
            textFile.close() #Stänger filen
        except IOError:
            print ("Filen finns inte") #Skriver ut om filen inte hittas
            return 0

        helper = Toplevel() #Fönster, längst fram
        helper.geometry("700x250") #Fönsterstorlek
        helper.title("Hjälpavsnitt") #Fönsterrubrik

        helpText = Label(helper, text=data, wraplength=680) #Bestämmer hur lång texten får vara/rad
        helpText.pack()        


    def higher(self):
        global turns
        global score
        decket.shuffle()
        decket.setValue()

        turns += 1 #Ökar värde i variabeln med 1, för varje gång användaren klickar på Gissa
        turnEnt.delete(0, END) #Tar bort allt ifrån Entry-widgeten
        turnEnt.insert(0, int(turns)) #Fyller den på nytt, men nu med ett nytt värde

        rank = CardValue
        compare = CardValueHist[-2]

        if (compare <= rank):
            mode.set("Bra jobbat! Fortsätt!")
            infoText.config(bg="Green")
            lower.config(state='active')
            score *= turns #Ökar värde i variabeln med 1, för varje gång användaren klickar på Gissa
            scoreTot.delete(0, END) #Tar bort allt ifrån Entry-widgeten
            scoreTot.insert(0, int(score)) #Fyller den på nytt, men nu med ett nytt värde


        else:
            mode.set("Tyvärr, du gissade fel") #Skriver meddelande
            infoText.config(bg="Red") #Bestämmer backgrund för meddelande
            higher.config(state='disable') #Ställer knappen som inaktiv
            lower.config(state='disable') #Ställer knappen om inaktiv
            restart.config(state='active') #Ställer knappen som aktiv
            loser.play()

    def lower(self):
        global turns
        global score
        decket.shuffle()
        decket.setValue()

        turns += 1 #Ökar värde i variabeln med 1, för varje gång användaren klickar på Gissa
        turnEnt.delete(0, END) #Tar bort allt ifrån Entry-widgeten
        turnEnt.insert(0, int(turns)) #Fyller den på nytt, men nu med ett nytt värde

        rank = CardValue
        compare = CardValueHist[-2]

        if (compare >= rank):
            mode.set("Bra jobbat! Fortsätt!")
            infoText.config(bg="Green")
            score *= turns #Ökar värde i variabeln med 1, för varje gång användaren klickar på Gissa
            scoreTot.delete(0, END) #Tar bort allt ifrån Entry-widgeten
            scoreTot.insert(0, int(score)) #Fyller den på nytt, men nu med ett nytt värde
        else:
            mode.set("Tyvärr, du gissade fel")
            infoText.config(bg="Red")
            higher.config(state='disable') #Ställer knappen som inaktiv
            lower.config(state='disable') #Ställer knappen om inaktiv
            restart.config(state='active') #Ställer knappen som aktiv
            turns += 1
            loser.play()

#Top-bakgrund
BannerBg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Python/projekt/bilder/card_bg.jpg"))
Banner = Label(win, text="This is a game", image=BannerBg)
Banner.pack(fill=BOTH)

#Textfält för spelstatus och välkomsttext
mode = StringVar()
mode.set("Welcome to High or Low Game")
infoText = Label(win, textvariable=mode, font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold"), bg="Yellow", bd=0.5, relief='solid')
infoText.pack(fill=BOTH)

decket = Deck()
game = game()
decket.populate()
decket.setValue()
game.higher
game.lower
decket.reset
game.helper

#Poäng och rundor
label = Label(win, bg="#188200", height=800)
label.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=BOTH)


#Korthållare
cardHolder = LabelFrame(win)
cardHolder.pack(anchor=N)

#Poäng och rundor
turnText = Label(label, text="Antal gissningar:", bg="#188200", font=("verdana", 10, "bold"))
turnText.pack(fill=BOTH, anchor=E)
turnEnt = Entry(label, bg="#188200", bd=0, font=("verdana", 15, "bold"), width=10, justify=CENTER)
turnEnt.pack(anchor=E)
scoreText = Label(label, text="Poäng:", bg="#188200", font=("verdana", 10, "bold"))
scoreText.pack(fill=BOTH, anchor=E)
scoreTot = Entry(label, bg="#188200", bd=0, font=("verdana", 15, "bold"), width=10, justify=CENTER)
scoreTot.pack(anchor=E)

#Knappar
buttonHolder = LabelFrame(win)
buttonHolder.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=S)

higher = Button(buttonHolder, text="+Högre", width=50, highlightthickness=5, command=lambda: game.higher())
higher.config(state='active')
higher.pack()

lower = Button(buttonHolder, text="-Lägre", width=50, highlightthickness=5, command=lambda: game.lower())
lower.config(state='disable')
lower.pack()

restart = Button(buttonHolder, text="=Börja om", width=50, highlightthickness=5, command=lambda: game.reset())
restart.config(state='disable')
restart.pack()

helpBg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Python/projekt/bilder/help.jpg").resize((85, 75)))
helpBtn = Button(label, text="?Hjälp", bg="#188200", image = helpBg, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, command=lambda: game.helper())
helpBtn.config(state='active')
helpBtn.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=SE)

win.mainloop()
```

Here it is the code for the method I made ​​to restore the game:

```
def reset(self):
    global turns
    global score     

    score = 1
    turns = 0 #Återställer värdet i
    decket = Deck()
    decket.populate()

    turnEnt.delete(0, END) #Tar bort allt ifrån Entry-widgeten
    turnEnt.insert(0, int(turns)) #Fyller den på nytt, men nu med ett nytt värde
    scoreTot.delete(0, END) #Tar bort allt ifrån Entry-widgeten
    scoreTot.insert(0, int(score)) #Fyller den på nytt, men nu med ett nytt värde

    lower.config(state='active')
    higher.config(state='active')
    restart.config(state='disable')
```

Comment: I don't know the concrete cause of your issue, but it looks like the use of global variables is the root of this problem. In general, creating a new instance of the class that wraps the logic of a game is enough to "reset" it, but here you have so many global variables that is is difficult to know what do you have to change.

Comment: I understand your point and I will fix this. But everything works as it should, except that the cards (canvas) does not disappear

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too reliant on many global variables, which makes a true reset function very difficult.

You should have one class that represents the game logic, and one that represents the gui. At startup, your GUI class can create an instance of a game class. The reset button can then delete the old game object and create a new one, effectively resetting all the game logic in a single statement. The only thing that's left is to have a function in your GUI class that updates the screen based on the current game state.

To make it a little easier, the GUI should pass itself to the game class so that the game class can call methods in the GUI. And since the GUI creates the game class, it can call methods in the game. For example, whenever something happens in the game logic it might want to call `self.gui.refresh()` to refresh the display.

Roughly, it looks something like this:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, gui):
        self.gui = gui
        self.turns = 0
        self.score = 0 
        ...

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        # create the GUI here...
        ...
        self.reset_button = tk.Button(..., command=self.reset)
        ...

        # last step is to create a new game (optional; you
        # could make the user click a "New Game" button)
        self.new_game()

    def new_game(self):
        # create new game instance, passing in a reference to this object
        self.game = Game(self)
        # reset the GUI
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        ...
        self.scoreText.configure(self.game.get_score())
        ...
```

Comment: It was a good tip my friend. I will try and see if I can achieve any success by your tip. Thanks